# Is there a way to extract data from API calls with Protractor

Tags: angular, rest, api, protractor

So let's say I have a form which I can submit and after submission this completed form will have a unique ID and will be stored in the DB. The issues is that after submitting a form next thing I need to do is to test functionality inside this submitted form.

On the front-end there is a list of submitted forms but the unique ID is not not displayed.
I need to open and test this particular form that I have just created.
When I take a look on the API calls I can see that my AUT is sending the POST call to external API

```
{
"owner":123123,
"id":010101,
"type":"someType"
}
```

The good thing is that when I open the submitted form it's ID is in url.
So I will be able to extract and save the ID which my AUT is sending to the external API I will be able then to go directly to this form simply by navigating to myaut/forms/010101
Is there a way (some library maybe?) to read the json data in this POST request?

p.s. Please don't suggest to mock the requests or to make direct API calls to the external API
Yes, the application is designed poorly so when user wants to open the form that he has just submitted user has to click over all forms until he will find the desired one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution and this is not necessarily a problem that should be handled by protractor. It's more suited for nodejs. You need to create a helper class/function to extract the ID from the database.

Your workflow would be:

1. Configure and submit form using protractor
2. use helper function to Query db and return relevant ID
3. Use the ID from step two to navigate to submitted form

---

```
// this is just an example
const id = dbHelper.getID(someQuery);
browser.get(`myaut/forms/${id}`);
```

I would be very surprised if you cannot find a package that already exists for the db you are using. There are node packages out there now for most databases that will allow you to query. If you don't have the connection string or credentials to the db, get them. There is no reason not to have read only access at the very least. Especially in this situation.

Comment: This totally make sense but the issue is don't know what data I'm looking for. I can use protractor-http-client library which is very handy but I need that one particular row of json at that particular moment. And protractor-http-client can only make and receive requests but not intercept it

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood. Is the json data you are looking for different than the data that would be returned from the database? I was assuming you could open the submitted form, extract the id from the url, and then use that id to query the db for the data you want.

Comment: The issue is that I won't know what data I should query for. As soon as form is submitted this submission has a unique ID and I want to know what this ID is to continue test on that particular form which I have just submitted. The application makes a POST request to the DB with that ID. But when I move to the submissions list I don't know which form I have just submitted (there is no time stamp either). Hope this makes sense

Comment: Yep, got it now. That's unfortunate. Is it possible to maybe ask the devs to change the behavior of the app so that it gives you something useful? A timestamp, or anything else unique that you can use. Is there any data submitted with the form that can be used to query the db? The data has to be mapped to the form somehow in the db. Otherwise how would it know what data to display when you open it back up? Wish I had more ideas but I'm really not sure how to tackle this one.